# defining a function without using ":"

Tags: python

I have been asked to define a function which is called `avg`. `avg` should calculate the average of two lists with the same amount of numbers - take all the numbers from both lists and calculate their average.
However, it is not allowed to use `:` nor more than one line (except `import` lines).

My closest try was:

```
//import line does not count as a line
import numpy
//the code line (only one is allowed)
avg=lambda lst1,lst2: numpy.mean(lst1+lst2)
```

My function properly calculates the average of the lists but it contains `:`, so it is not good enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "the average of two lists"?

Comment: if you're a beginner, one should not give you pointless tasks when there's a lot of interesting tasks to be done. Maybe they overproduced keyboards missing the colon key and want to flog them to python developpers?

Comment: I think what Jean-Francois is trying to point out is that "define a function without using a colon" is a pretty pointless programming task, since the obvious ways to do it (`lambda` and `def`) both _do_ require colons. Part of the Zen of Python (try `import this`) is "there should be one, and preferably only one, obvious way to do it". The non-obvious ways are only rarely better, unless serious optimization is required. Readability trumps execution speed until it doesn't.

Comment: I don't recall there are actually legal ways to define a function without colons... if we don't hack the language somehow.

Comment: [StackOverflow's topicality guidelines, per the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) call for something to be "a **practical**, answerable question". Practical value of this question is neigh impossible to observe (or, at minimum, not established in the question itself). See the [Puzzles & Code Golf StackExchange](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) as a location to which this question may be better-suited.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy might be practical. He might want to get through `eval()` verifiers or other validity checkers. And it's totally answerable as I've answered it below.

Comment: @Bharel, I'm only questioning "practical", not "answerable". If the OP is genuinely trying to get through a validity checker, they should include sufficient details to make their solution testable in the question. Certainly, it's easy to perform a security exploit without needing any function declarations, so a checker that tried to eliminate only function declarations would be effectively useless, serving no *practical* value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If someone asked you a pointless question, I would just give him a pointless answer. He deserves it.

```
import numpy  # You said it doesn't count as a line

# Take the : from dict's docstring.
exec("avg = lambda lst1, lst2{} numpy.mean(lst1+lst2)".format(dict.__doc__[213]))

>>> avg([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
2
```

Comment: I'm sorry for this pointless comment, but... you really made me laugh, thank you.

Comment: Your comment has a `:`, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I can escape it out with `\ `:
`# Take the \: from dict's docstring.`

Comment: Your icon has 4 sets of :  (you still get +1 upvote from me)

Answer (score 3):

Speaking of ridiculous, I suggest:

```
>>> exec(''.join(map(chr, [100, 101, 102, 32, 97, 118, 103, 40, 108, 115, 116, 49, 44, 32, 108, 115, 116, 50, 41, 58, 32, 114, 101,116, 117, 114, 110, 32, 48, 46, 53, 32, 42, 32, 115, 117, 109, 40, 108, 115, 116, 49, 32, 43, 32, 108, 115, 116, 50, 41, 32, 47, 32, 108, 101, 110, 40, 108, 115, 116, 49, 41])))
>>>
>>> avg([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])
4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use exec like in  Bharel's answer but use the `chr(58)`:

```
exec("avg = lambda lst1, lst2 " + chr(58) + " sum(lst1 + lst2, 0.) / (len(lst1) + len(lst2))")

print(avg([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))
```

Or if you really want to use numpy.mean:

```
exec("avg = lambda lst1, lst2 " + chr(58) + "numpy.mean(lst1+lst2)")
```

Comment: Yeah but why go the obvious way? dict's doc is way better. I think you're just jealous :-P btw, it's even py1/2/3 compatible! Working since 1999.